# how to identify messages sent together to the whatsapp cloud api number

Tags: node.js, whatsapi

I am currently using whatsapp cloud api webhook to receive msg to my server. It is working and am logging the msgs to console. I want to send 5 images together along with a caption the msgs are being sent and appear as a grp in the chat. But I can't seem to find any key-value pair that would suggest that these msgs were sent together at the same time. Is there a way to find out if the 5 images were sent together at the same time or were sent individually at different times or as separate msgs?

I read through the entire JSON object trying to find a key-value pair that would link msgs sent together at the same time similar to how telegram has media_group_id where you can identify that multiple images were sent together simultaneously

Comment: There is no way to send multiple media at a time, you can send it through the loop.